# Get the health status for a Google Vertex Endpoint

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Say I have an endpoint:

```py
from google.cloud.aiplatform import Endpoint
endpoint = Endpoint(endpoint_name="some_id",location = "location")
```

I can get predictions using `endpoint.predict()`, but how do I just make a health-check? I would've assumed that `endpoint.health()` exists but it doesn't and I can't find anything in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.Endpoint#google_cloud_aiplatform_Endpoint_preview).